# Product card doesn't show up more than once

Tags: php, html

I'm doing a school project about an e-commerce website. I created a product card to display each of the product and I got the data from my phpmyadmin database. The problem here is although I have two data in my database, the website only shows up one product.

This is my code :

```
<?php
session_start();
include('header.php');
include('serverconnection.php');
?>
<style>
  body{background-color: #333333;}

  .product-card {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height : 300px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 20px 30px 30px 30px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 3;
  overflow: hidden;}

  .product-card .shopping-cart{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;}

  .product-card .shopping-cart img{
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  object-fit: cover;}

  .product-card .shopping-cart i{
    display: flex;
    font-size: 30px;}

  .product-card .main-images{
  position: relative;
  height: 165px;}

  .product-card .main-images img{
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  object-fit: cover;
  left : 25px;
  z-index: -1;}

  .product-card .main-images img.active{opacity: 1;}

  .product-card .computer_details .computer_name{
    color: black;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 550;}
</style>
<?php
$sql_pilihan = "SELECT * FROM komputer";
$laksana_sql = mysqli_query($connection,$sql_pilihan);
if(mysqli_num_rows($laksana_sql)>0)
{
    echo"<hr>";
    foreach($laksana_sql as $pilihan)
    {
        echo"
        <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
        <div class='product-card'>
        <div class='shopping-cart'>
            <img src='image/".$pilihan['jenama'].".png'>
            <i class='bx bx-shopping-bag'></i>
        </div>
            <div class='main-images'>
                <img src='image/".$pilihan['kod_barang'].".png'>
            </div>
            <div class='computer_details'>
            <span class='computer_name'>".$pilihan['nama_barang']."</span>
            </div>
            <div class='price'>
            <span class='price_num'>RM ".$pilihan['harga']."</span><hr>
            </div>
            <div class='features'>
            <span class='pemproses_ic'>• Pemproses IC : ".$pilihan['pemproses_ic']."</span><br>
            <span class='pemproses_ic'>• Kapasiti RAM : ".$pilihan['kapasiti_RAM']."</span>
        </div>";
    }
}
else{echo "Tiada barangan yang telah direkodkan";}

?>
<?php
include('footer.php');
?>
```

and this is the result I got :
The website display : (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Xcxt.png)

Please help me how to display more than one product card.

Comment: are you sure the `<div class='product-card'>` closed properly? you are not missing `</div>` somewhere? though, after it fixed, your css definitely need some fix. ah right, a PSA, try to [html encode anything you print into UI properly to avoid XSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996122/how-to-prevent-xss-with-html-php).

Comment: Also `$laksana_sql` will not straight forward work in `foreach()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Closing upper-most parent div is missing

b) Don't add the same style sheet repeatedly through the loop, put it outside of the loop.

c) `echo` everything through PHP along with concatenation can be hard to read and understand, so you can separate them.

d)  `$laksana_sql` will not work straight-forward in the loop as you need to get results first from this resultset object.

Do it like below:

```
<?php
session_start();
include('header.php');
include('serverconnection.php');
?>
<style>
  body{background-color: #333333;}

  .product-card {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height : 300px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 20px 30px 30px 30px;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 3;
  overflow: hidden;}

  .product-card .shopping-cart{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;}

  .product-card .shopping-cart img{
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  object-fit: cover;}

  .product-card .shopping-cart i{
    display: flex;
    font-size: 30px;}

  .product-card .main-images{
  position: relative;
  height: 165px;}

  .product-card .main-images img{
  position: absolute;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  object-fit: cover;
  left : 25px;
  z-index: -1;}

  .product-card .main-images img.active{opacity: 1;}

  .product-card .computer_details .computer_name{
    color: black;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 550;}
</style>
<link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.0.7/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<?php
$sql_pilihan = "SELECT * FROM komputer";
$laksana_sql = mysqli_query($connection,$sql_pilihan);
$rows = mysqli_fetch_all($laksana_sql, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if($rows){ 
    echo"<hr>";
    foreach($rows as $pilihan){
?>
        
    <div class='product-card'>
        <div class='shopping-cart'>
            <img src='image/<?php echo $pilihan['jenama'];?>.png'>
            <i class='bx bx-shopping-bag'></i>
        </div>
        <div class='main-images'>
            <img src='image/<?php echo $pilihan['kod_barang'];?>.png'>
        </div>
        <div class='computer_details'>
            <span class='computer_name'><?php echo $pilihan['nama_barang'];?></span>
        </div>
        <div class='price'>
            <span class='price_num'>RM <?php echo $pilihan['harga'];?></span><hr>
        </div>
        <div class='features'>
            <span class='pemproses_ic'>• Pemproses IC : <?php echo $pilihan['pemproses_ic'];?></span><br>
            <span class='pemproses_ic'>• Kapasiti RAM : <?php echo $pilihan['kapasiti_RAM'];?></span>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php
    }}else{
        echo "Tiada barangan yang telah direkodkan";
    }
?>
<?php
include('footer.php');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

please note that you have forgotten to close the `<div class='features'>` tag so it is considering last div as close tag and `<div class='product-card'>` tag remains open so it is not displaying cards